# Algorithm to find amount of unique number sequences without repeating numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, integers, pattern-recognition

Basically what I am wondering is what the algorithm would look like to find the amount of number sequences without repeating numbers for any given positive number?

For Example, if you use 3 (which will use all numbers between 1-3):
you get 6 possible outcomes: {1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}

Another Example with 4 will result in 24 possibilities:
{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,4,3}, {1,3,2,4}, {1,3,4,2}, {1,4,2,3}, {1,4,3,2}, etc.

Is there an algorithm that can find this amount? Thank in advance and hopefully this wasn't a blatantly obvious answer.

Comment: There are $n!$ permutations on $n$ numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Wikipedia article about the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Applications). The first mentioned application is:

> There are $n!$ different ways of arranging $n$ distinct objects into a sequence, the permutations of those objects.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Although I think my high-school Algebra teacher will be very disappointed in me that I forgot about factorials. Thank you for the quick response.